# Reading multiple files from Google Storage using Python client asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read a list of files uploaded to a Google Storage bucket and load them to a file/buffer so that I can perform some aggregation on these files.

So far, I am able to read the contents of all the files in a serial manners (each blob object from the iterator that contains all the files in the bucket). However, there are thousands of files that I have uploaded to google cloud storage and even reading these files is taking a considerable amount of time.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import json
import time

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
manager = Manager()
finalized_list = manager.list()

# Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('.serviceAccountCredentials.json')
bucket_name = "bucket-name"

def list_blobs():
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    return blobs


def read_blob(blob):
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob_object = bucket.blob(blob)
    with blob_object.open("r") as f:
        converted_string = f.read()
        print(converted_string)
        finalized_list.append(converted_string)

def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    print("Start time: ", start_time)

    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count)
    blobs = list_blobs()
    pool.map(read_blob, [blob for blob in blobs])
    
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Time taken: ", elapsed_time, " seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As in the above code snippet, I thought of using multiprocessing in python to read each blob object in the bucket, however, since the blob object returned by google cloud storage is not a standard iterator/list object, I am getting an error that says `Pickling client objects is not explicitly supported`

Is there any other way that I could use to fetch and read thousands of files from cloud storage quickly using a **python** script?

Comment: you might want to take a look at [gcloud.aio](https://talkiq.github.io/gcloud-aio/gcloud/aio.html) which is an async implementation of a number of the GCP API's.

Comment: You could try using multithreading since I would think the program is mostly waiting for network requests to complete. By the way: (1) You can replace `[blob for blob in blobs]` with just `blobs`. (2) Having `manager = Manager(); finalized_list = manager.list()` at global scope is a disaster if you run this under an OS that creates child tasks using the *spawn* method, such as Windows (each process will be appending to its own list assuming your blob could be pickled).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I did a years ago with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor (I did a cpu heavy task. You can as well use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor if you're mostly waiting for a return)

```
from google.cloud import storage

# multi CPU
import concurrent.futures

# progress bar
from tqdm import tqdm

bucket_name = 'your_bucket'
path_to_folder = 'your_path_to_the_files'
file_ending = '.pkl'

kwargs_bucket={
    'bucket_or_name': bucket_name,
    #'max_results': 60, # comment if you want to run it on all files
    'prefix': path_to_folder
}

kwargs_process_pool={
    #'max_workers': 1 #comment if you want full speed
}

# a list to store the output
results = []

# connect to the bucket
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

# multi CPU OCR
futures = []
# progress bar
with tqdm(total=sum(1 for blob in client.list_blobs(**kwargs_bucket) if blob.name.endswith(file_ending)), position=0, leave=True) as pbar:
    #ProcessPoolExecutor
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(**kwargs_process_pool) as executor:
        # getting all the files from the bucket
        for blob in client.list_blobs(**kwargs_bucket):
            # skip the folder
            if not blob.name.endswith(file_ending):
                continue
            # calling the class above with the ProcessPoolExecutor
            futures.append(executor.submit(your_function, blob.name))

        # updating the progress bar and checking the return
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            pbar.update(1)
            if future.result() != '':
                results.append(future.result())
```

I figured out the hard way, that you should only pass variables and not objects to your_function with the executor. That's why I'm passing blob.name.

Hope that helps